# (CodeIgniter) What is the proper way of loading model into view

Tags: codeigniter

Help me please, I am new to codeigniter, I am just trying to create a simple calculator using codeigniter.

**My controler**

```
public function loan_calc (){
    $this->load->view('/includes/head1');
    $this->load->view('/includes/nav');
    $this->load->model('model_loancal');
    $sagot = $this->model_loancal->calculate();
    $this->load->view('membersportal_loan', $sagot);
    $this->load->view('/includes/footer1');
}
```

**Model**

```
class Model_loancal extends CI_Model{
    public function calculate(){
        if(isset($_POST['calc'])){ 
            $num = $_POST['num'];
            $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
            $num3 = $_POST['num3'];
            $num4 = $_POST['num4'];
            $totals = $num+$num2+$num3+$num4;
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```html
    <form class="col s12" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>members-portal/loan"> 
      <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input id="num" type="text" name="num" class="validate">
              <label for="num">First</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input id="num2" type="text" name="num2" class="validate">
              <label for="num2">Second</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input id="num3" type="text" name="num3" class="validate">
              <label for="num3">Third</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input id="num4" type="text" name="num4" class="validate">
              <label for="num4">Fourth</label>
            </div>
      </div>
      <center><button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="calc">Submit
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button></center>
    </form>
   <?php 
     echo "$totals";
    ?>
```

Help me please, I am new to codeigniter, I am just trying to create a simple calculator using codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a model in the controller

`$this->load->model('modelname');`

Assign this model to a variable like this

`$data['model_obj'] = $this->modelname;`

and assign this data array to your view template

`$this->load->view('template', $data);`

Use $model_obj object in the view template for calling model methods

`$model_obj->any_method();`

Comment: Thankyou sir,I get it

Comment: If this worked for you then please Mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You load model in controller constractor or function where you want to call
if you load this in a constractor its will be automatic load when any function of this class will call call model in constractor 
the code like below

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

load any view of this class any function this model automatic load of this view. You can call model form this view

```
$this->load->view('view_name');
```

and from just call any function of this model like below

```
<?php $data= $this->model->get_data($table); ?>
```